# Do Federal agents enforce state import regulations at airports?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, california, prohibited-items

[Kangaroo products, including skin and meat, are banned in the state of California](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/07/25/world/americas/25iht-roo.4.6828538.html).  However, there is no federal, US-wide prohibition on either.

Customs inspectors at airports are usually employees of [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://www.cbp.gov/) (CBP) or the [U.S. Department of Agriculture](https://www.usda.gov/) (USDA), both of which are Federal agencies.  (By contrast, [California Border Protection Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Border_Protection_Stations) staff checking travellers coming in by road are state employees.)

So the question: **if you arrive in California, and a CBP/USDA employee spots a prohibited-in-California-only kangaroo product, will they take any action?**  Or is this literally not their problem?

Obligatory disclaimer: I'm asking out of curiosity, not advocating breaking the law, and regardless of the answer you risk fines of up to US$5,000 and possible jail time if a California state inspector *does* show up at the airport.

Comment: Is it not in CITES? So valid also in US and many other countries). And in such case you should check what are the restrictions.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Red and eastern grey kangaroos, the "commercial" species, are *very* far from endangered, there's up to 50 million of them bouncing around when it's wet & lush.

Comment: Yes, but I find also some flora in CITES is absolutely not endangered, but still on the list. The *decision by committee* are often not logical.

Comment: I've seen packaged kangaroo meat for sale at a mainstream grocery store in Colorado, so it's surely not a nationwide ban.  (Albeit that was a few years ago, but well after 2007.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [California Penal Code § 830.85](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=830.85) :

> 830.85. Notwithstanding any other law, United States Immigration and Customs Enforcement officers and United States Customs and Border
> Protection officers are not California peace officers.

This would imply that USCIS/CBP staff are not legally able to enforce California state laws, including the one you have referenced. Legally they could likely detain you and hand you over to a California peace officer (eg, Police or Sherriff) if they believed you were in breach of a California law, and indeed this is what they will do for passengers where there is a state warrant issued for their arrest - but it seems very unlikely they would do so in a situation like you described.

However in the case you've mentioned it's largely a moot point.  If you look at the article you referenced, it states that the state has " ... banned the **sale** of kangaroo ...".  The relevant legislation is [California Penal Code § 653o](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=653o), which states that it is "*unlawful to import into this state **for commercial purposes**, to possess with **intent to sell**, or to **sell** within the state*".  Simply possessing such items is not illegal, nor is bringing them into the state - at least not unless you were bringing in a commercial quantity in which case the first condition may be triggered.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for digging up the actual state law!  Although the putative kangaroo-importer probably still shouldn't jump for joy, since there are federal regulations on importing any kind of animal meat.

Comment: @lambshaanxy And even if there weren't, one would expect CA to place their own inspectors at the ports.

Comment: For what it's worth, the California law most likely _has to be_ written this way in order to be valid and enforceable. The Constitution is very clear that the [federal government has the power to regulate interstate and international commerce](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/commerce_clause). State laws which contradict federal decisions (including a federal decision to _not_ have a given rule) regarding interstate or international commerce are invalid and unenforceable.

Comment: Note to self, don't resell my [Copa Mundials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adidas_Copa_Mundial) to anyone in California, but at least I can play in a tournament there without getting arrested.